# Change ENTIRE site if logged in using PHP

Tags: php, coding-style

I'm creating a website for learning purposes only. I have made it so in the index.php is a basic login form. It is setup with MySQL. I want to make it so when you are *not* logged in you see the form website in index.php, and when you *are* logged in you see an entire different site in index.php as well. I know how to check if i am logged in or not, so the basic question is: can i do something like this type of style:

```
  if(loggedIn){
    include 'loggedInSite.php';
  }else{
    include 'notLoggedInSite.php';
  }
```

Or does it have to be totally different?
Or should I do something along these lines:

```
  if(loggedIn){
    echo "<html>Whole site</html>";
  }
```

Echoing out the entire website in a simple echo function?

Comment: I think the first approcach looks better although both should work

Comment: Also please use `require` instead of `include`, include suggests that the file is not necessary (which is rarely the case).  I know it's psuedo code but.. in many projects it hasn't been ;].

Answer (score 3):

Your first example should work just fine with a slight alteration:

```
if($loggedIn){
  include 'loggedInSite.php';
}else{
  include 'notLoggedInSite.php';
}
```

Comment: This way is probably cleaner than the second option. It might be easy to step on toes if you have both pages in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just redirect them to a different page if they are not logged in?

Or

What you wrote should work

```
if($loggedIn){
  include 'loggedInSite.php';
}else{
  include 'notLoggedInSite.php';
}
```